# Is there an easy way to see that $\mathbb{A}^r \setminus \{0\}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^r$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question says it all really, is there an easy way to see that these schemes aren't isomorphic without showing that the cohomology of some sheaf on $\mathbb{A}^r\setminus \{0\}$ doesn't vanish?

I'd like to be able to say that the underlying topological spaces aren't isomorphic, but this isn't easy to see either since there are non-closed points and this isn't affine space over a field but over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If they're isomorphic over $\Bbb Z$, then they'll be isomorphic after a base change (in particular, if you show that they're not isomorphic as $\Bbb C$ schemes, then they won't be isomorphic as $\Bbb Z$ schemes).

Comment: Alternatively, I suspect you can generalize the relatively well-known argument that $X = \mathbb A^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ isn't affine by examining the inclusion $X\to\mathbb{A}^2$ and looking at global sections (although if you do this, you'll have to treat $r = 1$ separately).

Comment: @Stahl It's the exact same thing, person who I assume is Joe. Namely, if $X$ is any affine scheme and $Z\subseteq X$ is some closed subset of codimension at least $2$, then $U:=X-Z$ is not even affine. Indeed, by Algebraic Hartog's Lemma the inclusion map $U\hookrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to \mathcal{O}_U(U)$ which, if $U$ were affine, would imply that the inclusion $U\hookrightarrow X$ is an isomorphism—it's not even surjective.

Comment: If one wants to be fancy, it's easy to see that $H^{n-1}_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\})=0$ whereas $H^{n-1}_{\text{dR}}(\mathbb{A}^n)=0$. This works for all $n$. Here, of course, dR stands for de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Another, simpler, argument would be that if $\mathbf A^r$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf A^r\setminus\{0\}$ over $\mathbf Z$, then it would also hold over $\mathbf F_2$. Which cannot be true since the first has $2^r$ rational points over $\mathbf F_2$, while the other has only $2^r-1$. However, this is still not a topological argument that you are looking for...